# Android ImageView.setImage* vs. BitmapFactory.decode*

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

I'm currently facing several performance issues (out-of-memory) when handling a vast amount of bitmaps. As this is just a problem that can be fixed I'm wondering if anybody can explain me the difference in using the following methods.

If I only want to load an image into an ImageView I usually use:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.id));
```

If I want to sample the drawable beforehand I usually use (here without sampling):

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.id);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

My question is related to performance optimisation. I'm wondering whether it is better to provide as many drawables as possible using the different drawable folders (so these drawables nearly fit the required resolution for the different devices) or if it is better to sample high-quality drawables? What is setImageDrawable doing internally? Does it decode the resources using the BitmapFactory, just without sampling? There seems to be a trade-off between the actual size of the app and the cpu- and memory-load during runtime.

Comment: You can see source code of ImageView here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29

Answer (score 0):

if you're concerned about apk size, then having as many drawables as possible is not the ideal way to go. but dont forget, when you decode a bitmap, you can pass a sample size so it will scale down to the screen size and only give you the pixels you need, so older phones with smaller screens wont need to decode 8mp images.

check [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I know how to sample images using BitMapFactory.Options. Indeed, this knowledge pointed me to my question. One interessting finding in the source code is that `setImageBitmap` is the same then `setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm))` and that the developers stated to not frequently use the `setImageBitmap()` method: _if this (the method) is used frequently, may handle bitmaps explicitly to reduce the intermediate drawable object_